# get size of InputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to encrypt an `InputStream` which I am getting from `FileItem.getInputStream();` and I want to know the encrypted stream's length.

If it would be a simple `FileInputStream`, I could have tried `File#length()` or `FileInputStream#getChennal().size()` though not sure even those would have given me exactly what I want, but, in this case what I have is an `InputStream` (the encrypted one) and I want to find length of the same, I tried searching on Internet but there I could not find any efficient solution to that.

Please help

Comment: Isn't [`FileItem#getSize()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getSize%28%29) what you need?

Comment: Why don't you use Java 7's file API? It has `Files.size()`

Comment: He wants to know the size of the encrypted stream.

Comment: @bereal : no because it will give me size of stream(file) before encryption

Comment: @VD' then it depends on the encryption algorithm and mode of operation.

Comment: well i can share those details too but ultimately what we want is.. efficient way of knowing length of an InputStream

Comment: @VD' I'm a bit confused: you have an input stream which you want to encrypt. You can know the length of that stream from its `FileItem`. Now, you want to know the length of data after encryption, right?

Comment: Then, that would depend on the encryption algorithm, mode, padding etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50045/discussion-between-vd-and-bereal)

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the whole stream for that. Streams are probably not even complete when you start reading from them, so the size may not be known at that time.

Comment: Efficient one my friend, this one is there everywhere on the internet! is it advisable to achieve it this way, i may be using files in GBs

Comment: @VD': Use a streaming form of encryption - there are plenty of those around. Why do you need the length ahead of time?

Comment: I actually need to store it on Cloud, and Cloud API needs it :(

Comment: If the CloudAPI does only retrieve a final byte[] you need to load the whole stream into memory anyways. edit: if you want to upload gigabytes at once into the cloud...have fun...

Comment: Why don't you just write the encrypted stream to another file and then transfer that file? With Java 7's API it is as easy as two `File.copy()`s away

Answer (score 2):

You can output whats in InputStream and get the length

```
ObjA = new ObjA;

while( more message to read ){
ObjA = inputStreamObj.read();
}

System.out.println(ObjA.length());
```