# Will available() on CipherInputStream give full size of stream always?

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream

I have a `CipherInputStream` created from an `InputStream` and `Cipher` passed to its constructor.

I want to know the size of that stream, is there any way of doing the same?
will `available()` give me the result what I expect?

I know answers like read the stream to determine same and such inefficient ones easily available on internet, but I want an efficient way of doing the same.

I already asked one question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508428/get-size-of-inputstream-in-java) for the same issue but there I did not mention exact class of the stream. also I tried searching on the internet but could not find any proper answer.

Comment: Short answer no. The very definition of a stream is that it is a collection of indeterminate length.

Comment: any other efficient alternative?

Comment: No. You **must** consume an entire stream to determine its length.

Answer (score 0):

No, `available` cannot tell you the full size of the stream because it depends on the underlying stream.